# Eigenvalues of the Jacobian matrix for shallow water equations

Tags: partial-differential-equations, matrix-equations, jacobian

To my knowledge, the Jacobian matrix `A` for the 1D shallow water equations is

```
|0               1  |
|-u^2 + g * h    2*u|
```

that is known to give the eigenvalues such as

```
Lamba1 = u - sqrt(9.81 * h)
Lamba2 = u + sqrt(9.81 * h)
```

Now, let's assume the values as follows:

```
h = 1
u = 2
Lamba1 = u - sqrt(9.81 * h) = 2 - sqrt(9.81 * 1) = -3.13
Lamba2 = u + sqrt(9.81 * h) = 2 + sqrt(9.81 * 1) = +3.13
```

If the identity matrix `I` is

```
|1    0|
|0    1|
```

My question is then: why is **NEITHER** `det|A - Lambda1 x I|` **NOR** `det|A - Lamba2 x I|` equal zero? Have I misunderstood the concept here?

Any advices would be appreciated. Thank you.